# Adjust figure size with respect to the axes size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say I create a simple plot with matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plot stuff etc .. .
```

After I finished the plotting routines I want to adjust the size of my figure (but keeping all aspect ratios the same), such that the total height of `ax` is set to a constant value i.e. 3 inches.
Is there a nice and short way to archieve this ?

EDIT: I know how to change the figure size, but here i want to adjust it according to the size of the axes.

Comment: I want to change the size with respect to the axes this is slightly different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the function to set figure height in inch unit:

```
def set_axes_height(ax, h):
    fig = ax.figure
    aw, ah = np.diff(ax.transAxes.transform([(0, 0), (1, 1)]), axis=0)[0]
    fw, fh = fig.get_size_inches()
    dpi = fig.get_dpi()
    scale = h / (ah / dpi)
    fig.set_size_inches(fw*scale, fh*scale, forward=True)
```

Comment: Thx, that's what i was looking for, I didn't know the `ax.figure` attribute. Just one thing how exactly does `np.diff(ax.transAxes.transform([(0, 0), (1, 1)]), axis=0)[0]` work?

Comment: `ax.transAxes`  transforms point in Axes coordinate to Screen coordinate. in Axes coordinate (0, 0) is the left bottom point, (1, 1) is the top right point. The `np.diff(...)` calculate the width and height of the Axes object in screen coordinate.