# Python - Matplotlib: change the axes sizes

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, axes

I would like draw figures in matplotlib such as in MATLAB where the plots automatically sizes and fill "better" the entire figure dimension.
[image: For example here the image has too much white space]
[image: Here the plot is too small with respect to the size of the figure].

The code that i have used for the 2nd image is:

```
fig7, ax7 = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
    linenp = plt.Line2D([0, 0], [0, 0])
    linep = plt.Line2D([0, 0], [0, 0])
    for i in range(X_boh.shape[1]):
        linenp, = ax7.plot(X_boh[:, i], Y_boh[:, i], Z_boh[:, i], 'b')  # , linewidth=2)
        linep, = ax7.plot(X_newnew[:, i], Y_newnew[:, i], Z_newnew[:, i], 'r--')
    linenp.set_label('Non planar')
    linep.set_label('Planar')
    ax7.set_xlabel('x')
    ax7.set_ylabel('y')
    ax7.set_zlabel('z')
    ax7.legend()
    ax7.view_init(elev=0, azim=-90)
    ax7.set_title(f"Slicing non planar path vs planar - step {h} [mm]")
```

I tried the suggestion proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675439/adjust-figure-size-with-respect-to-the-axes-size) but it does not solve.
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: have you tried `plt.tight_layout()`?

Comment: This problem is related to your 3D projection. These images are interactive and can be viewed from different angles. Matplotlib creates enough space that the largest isometric projection has enough space on the shorter axis of the figure. You can set a different aspect ratio for the three axes to fill the space `ax.set_box_aspect([3,2,1])` but I doubt this is what you intend to do.

Comment: @mozway I have tried plt.tight_layout() but it does not work.

Comment: @Mr.T I had set such as set_box_aspect(np.ptp(X), np.ptp(Y), np.ptp(Z)). But nothing have changed. Anyway, thank you for the explanation